# Cannot open the default profile on Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set firefox default profile with the folowing code in java:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

It doesn't work for me,any ideea why ?

I need to open the same profile with selenium webdriver because I need to open the browser with the login detailes saved from another session of browser.If anyone know another way to do that please help me.

Comment: i think it is not possible to use the credentials saved in different session

Comment: What is the exception being thrown? Even if you get the profile to open, it will not remember login creds. Selenium clears cache for every session. Maybe you could get the creds from the page and store them locally, then access your data store in the next session to use them... Can you explain more what exactly you are trying to accomplish? There may be a better solution.

Comment: I found another way to rezolve my particular problem,but I will try your ideea with storing locally the credentails and then load that in another session.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to create a new firefox profile.
To do this, please follow the below mentioned steps :-

1. close all the browser sessions of firefox.
2. ctrl+R and enter "firefox.exe -p"
3. you will see a create profile wizard and click on "Create Profile".
4. click next and add name like "profile1" and Finish it.
5. Now, "Profile1 will also get listed in profiles"
6. Double click on "profile1" , open your URL and provide credentials. Don't forget to click on "Remember Password"
7. Mozilla profile stores at "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xyz.profile1".
8. Now, write your code as :-

   FirefoxProfile profile1= new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xyz.profile1"));
   WebDriver driver1= new FirefoxDriver(profile1);

Note :- xyz is an alphanumeric value, which would be different . please take care of that also
UserName is your system's user name

Comment: I will try that tomorow.Thank you !

Comment: Sure!!
Please try it out and let me know, if any further information is required.

Thanks,
Anil